# How does Appium/UiAutomator actually see composables?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, appium, android-uiautomator

I have been rewriting my app to Jetpack Compose, and I already have existing Appium tests.  After rewriting (using testTag modifiers to replace what used to be resource IDs) all of my tests work fine.  So I am not asking for help with getting things working, but I am trying to understand *how* it works. When I look at the App Source tab in Appium, I see this:

[image: appium app source]

But this screen is just an Activity with a `ComposeView` created with the `setContent` extension. How does Appium see a `Column` with a `verticalScroll` modifier as a `ScrollView`, and a `TextField` as an `EditText`, etc? I know Compose is not just creating Views under the hood, so where is this mapping being done?  I tried searching the UiAutomator and Appium source code and could not find the right code.

Anyone out there have any expertise here to help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appium uses [UiAutomatorViewer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/aecdc4a/uiautomator/utils/uiautomatorviewer/src/com/android/uiautomator/UiAutomatorViewer.java), which you can find in `Android\Sdk\tools\bin`.

We can look at the source to find [ScreenshotAction](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/aecdc4a/uiautomator/utils/uiautomatorviewer/src/com/android/uiautomator/actions/ScreenshotAction.java), which uses [DumpCommand](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/jb-mr2-release/uiautomator/cmds/uiautomator/src/com/android/commands/uiautomator/DumpCommand.java), which dumps the view as XML using [AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/jb-dev/uiautomator/library/src/com/android/uiautomator/core/AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java).

Every composable has [AccessibilityNodeInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo), where the className property is the same as the XML equivalent class name.

You can find at least some of the "mapping" from compose to xml class names in [AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.ui/ui/1.0.0-beta02-source/androidx/compose/ui/platform/AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt.html).

If the composable has vertical scrolling, the className will be `android.widget.ScrollView`, like this:

```
val yScrollState = semanticsNode.config.getOrNull(SemanticsProperties.VerticalScrollAxisRange)
val scrollAction = semanticsNode.config.getOrNull(SemanticsActions.ScrollBy)
if (yScrollState != null && scrollAction != null) {
   info.className = "android.widget.ScrollView"
}
```

A lot of the mapping is also based on `Role`:

```
        semanticsNode.config.getOrNull(SemanticsProperties.Role)?.let {
            when (it) {
                Role.Button -> info.className = "android.widget.Button"
                Role.Checkbox -> info.className = "android.widget.CheckBox"
                Role.Switch -> info.className = "android.widget.Switch"
                Role.RadioButton -> info.className = "android.widget.RadioButton"
                Role.Tab -> info.roleDescription = AccessibilityRoleDescriptions.Tab
                Role.Image -> info.className = "android.widget.ImageView"
            }
        }
```

That's one of the reasons it's important to set a Role for you custom composables. Like:

```
@Composable 
fun CustomButton() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics {
            role = Role.Button
        }
    )
}
```